# Solving summation; ( double sum).

Tags: summation, riemann-zeta

I found the expression to the sum of powers long ago and ofcours I think it is true but i don't know for sure, the problem is, it's little though for me to test and try it out. Also i'd like to know how should i prove it.

for k>=0
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n} m^{k+1} =\sum^{k}_{s=0}\sum^{s}_{i=0} {s \choose i}{n+1 \choose s+2}(n-i)^{k} (-1)^{s+i} $$

I revised this because i was looking for additional ways to get the zeta function, this was the formula were i needed it:
$\zeta(-s)= 1/(2^s-1)*(2^s\sum_{n=1}^{m/2} n^s +2^s\sum_{n=1}^{(m-1)/2} n^s-\sum_{n=1}^{m} n^s$)

After using both formulas is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: For me, I always remember the formula for sum of powers as $\sum_{k=0}^x k^p = \frac{B_{p+1}(x+1) - B_{p+1}(0)}{p+1}$ where $B_p(x)$ is the [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials). If your formula is correct, one should be able to derive it from the generating function of the Bernoulli polynomials pretty easily.

Comment: Well thats more or less the question. Since i'm not too familiar myself with the bernoulli numbers/ polynomials i would love to see how you would create them out of this formula, again if it's correct ofcours. But i start looking into it and they seem really usefull.  Thanks inadvance!

Comment: If this makes sense, this is how i got the summation $$^{s}\sum^{n}_{m=1}m^k=n .^{s}\sum^{n}_{m=1}m^{k-1}-s*.^{s+1}\sum^{n}_{m=1}(m-1)^{k-1}$$ I hope i wrote this correct down, since i got this before i was used to summation notation at all. The little s before the sum means it's the s'th sum. so the s'th sum till n, over a lineair function would be (n+s+1)!/(n-1)!/(s+1)!. I bet you get what i mean with the s'th sum. And this formula above i use to derive the rest, since I write my formula in terms of this basic know summation.